# Mettere un'immagine come sfondo

Tags: css

Ho un problema! Non riesco a mettere un'immagine come sfondo per il mio sito.Ho provato diversi modi ma non hanno funzionato.Per esempio background-image: url(percorso file)

Comment: English please!

Comment: non puoi rispondere in italiano?

Comment: Nope. This is an English language site.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
body {
  background-image: url("https://media.istockphoto.com/photos/picking-the-right-paint-paint-sample-color-swatch-picture-id92241441?b=1&k=20&m=92241441&s=170667a&w=0&h=OudUCphkJO9Gx9AdVpYIIypg48ELx72Zd46W818fTa8=");
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!